# How to make R display 19 digit number as it is stored?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset with a key column which is basically a 19 digit integer.

I'm using tibbles so I use `options(pillar.sigfig = 22)` to display larger numbers and not scientific notation.

Problem is, I notice that the number stored in the column and the one that is displayed are slightly different, to be specific last 3 digits are different.

E.g

```
options(pillar.sigfig = 22)
x <- 1099324498500011011
```

But when I try to return the number I get 1099324498500011**008**.

I'm not sure why R would change the last 3 digits and since it is a key, it makes my data unusable for analysis.

I have tried the usual `options(scipen = 999)` for suppressing scientific notation but it does not seem to work on tibbles.

How do I get the same 19 digit number as I intend to store it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry to be bearer of bad news but R only has

- a numeric type (`double`) using 64 bits and approximately sixteen decimals precision
- an integer type (`int`) using 32 bits

There is nothing else. You may force the print function to *show you* nineteen digits but that just means ... you are looking at three digits of randomness.

19 digits for (countable) items are common, and often provided by (signed or unsigned) `int64_t` types.  Which R does *not have natively* but approximates via the `integer64` call in the `bit64` package.

So the following may be your only workaround:

```
> suppressMessages(library(bit64))
> x <- as.integer64("123456790123456789")
> x
integer64
[1] 123456790123456789
> x - 1
integer64
[1] 123456790123456788
>
```

The good news is that `integer64` is reasonably well supported by `data.table` and a number of other packages.

PS It really is 19 digits where it bites:

```
> as.integer64(1.2e18) + 1
integer64
[1] 1200000000000000001
> as.integer64(1.2e19) + 1
integer64
[1] <NA>
Warning message:
In as.integer64.double(1.2e+19) : NAs produced by integer64 overflow
>
```